# Oracle CONSTRAINT vs, CONSTRAINT *Using Index*

Tags: sql, oracle, create-table, unique-constraint

If a table has a constraint but no index, can I assume that the only difference is that I am leaving it to Oracle to determine how determine whether changes to the table violate the constraint, perhaps resulting in Oracle having to do table scans to determine it?

```
CREATE TABLE SchemaName."Table1" (
  field_one VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  field_two VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  field_three DATE NOT NULL,
  (etc)
  CONSTRAINT client_iu1 UNIQUE (field_one,field_two,field_three)
);
```

vs.

```
CREATE TABLE SchemaName."Table1" (
  field_one VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  field_two VARCHAR2(30 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  field_three DATE NOT NULL,
  (etc)
   CONSTRAINT client_ak1 UNIQUE (field_one,field_two,field_three) USING INDEX fds_base.client_iu1
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle creates the index in all cases for `unique` (and `primary key` constraints).

The `using index` statement allows you to either:

- Specify the name of the index in the *constraint* statement.
- Using an existing index for a new constraint.

In fact, I don't find either of these particularly useful in practice.  If you don't given an explicit index, Oracle creates the appropriate index for the constraint.

Comment: Glad you specified.  Not all types of constraints create indexes.

Comment: @AaronLS . . . I think `using index` is only allows on unique and primary key indexes.  The question would not apply to any other type of constraint.

Comment: I'm not talking about the `using index` clause, I'm talking about the automatic creation of indexes for constraints.  Some people seem to think indexes are created for all types of constraints, which is not true.  You're statement is accurate and indicates that only certain types of constraints automatically create an index.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If columns used for constraint are already indexed, Oracle will use that index.

Otherwise, it'll create one on its own.

In any case, there *will* be a unique index, and rows will be constrained by it.